# Simplify if checking for both has values and both are equal

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simplify this if statement to be more readable,
the logic checks if both `x` and `y` has value different than `Undefined`, and return false if they are not equal.

```
bool IsBothMatch(MyClassX x, MyClassY y)
{
    if (y.MyEnumVal != MyEnum.Undefined &&
        x.MyEnumVal != MyEnum.Undefined)
    {
        if (x.MyEnumVal != y.MyEnumVal)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: seems you should post this on review.stackexchange.com

Comment: If((x.val == y.val) && ((x.val != undefined) && (y.val != undefined)) return true;else return false;

Comment: @HimBromBeere Unfortunately review.stackexchange.com is not active as SO

Comment: @mshwf Which doesn´t change that questions about working code should go there.

Comment: it's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions BTW

Comment: *"more readable"* That's pretty readable. Did you mean shorter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can condense this into a single statement:

```
bool IsBothMatch(MyClassX x, MyClassY y) {
  return x.MyEnumVal == MyEnum.Undefined
      || y.MyEnumVal == MyEnum.Undefined
      || x.MyEnumVal == y.MyEnumVal;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Igor, thanks but I need the code will return true if `y.MyEnumVal` is equal to `MyEnum.Undefined`

Comment: @ShaharShokrani - done. Just invert and use logical `or` (`||`)

Answer (score 1):

If you're comparing two similar classes you can inherit `IEquatable<T>`

You inherit on the class

```
public class MyClassX : IEquatable<MyClassX>
{

}
```

You can then compare the two

```
MyClassX.Equals(MyClassY);
```